# meaning of elsewhere-

Tags: meaning-in-context

**[SOURCE](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zc16inF9T5wC&q=During+recent+months+he+has+been+repeatedly+accused+of+having+%22sold+out%22&dq=During+recent+months+he+has+been+repeatedly+accused+of+having+%22sold+out%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB5rGB1crUAhUG4YMKHUhNA0IQ6AEIKDAA)**    (Google books search)

What is the exact meaning of the following text? It is an excerpt from a political text with a special shortened style. The word "elsewhere" is specially problematic.

> During recent months he has been repeatedly accused of having “sold out” to US. He is clearly worried lest an agreement involving prices lower than he has been willing publicly to accept elsewhere.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The style is so severely shortened that the second "sentence" in your paragraph is _not_ a complete sentence in English. What is the source of this text?

Comment: Hi! it is an excerpt of a telegram from the US State Department, sent in 1953. Nothing in it is omitted by me. It has a formidable style.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (a) the meaning of ***elsewhere*** is easily established using a dictionary, and (b) the cited context is a *telegram*, the precise wording of which is primarily dictated by space considerations, not grammar.

Comment: How is this question off-topic? Even if it's from a telegram, it is still a piece of text. The OP has presented something they don't understand in a specific context and are asking for help. Isn't that the point of English language learners?

Comment: @Phil14 The usage of _elsewhere_ is not "problematic", though, except to a reader who neglects to consult a dictionary. We are here to help, but only when the dictionary, for some reason, does not provide useful guidance.

Comment: Of course the text is truncated! There is no period after _elsewhere._ See the source added above, which is undoubtedly where you found this.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Agreed. Either it's truncated beyond belief (we are still waiting for the verb of which "an agreement" is the subject!) or the writer unfortunately thought "lest" meant "about".

Comment: @LukeSawczak It is _certainly_ truncated, and the OP knows perfectly well that it is. See the link to the source which I added to the question.

Comment: @P.E.Dant <strike>I did but can't find more than a tiny window of the relevant page that ends on the top half of the "elsewhere" line. Where can I see more, e.g. the lack of a period you mention?</strike> Never mind; I performed a new search and got this much out of the preview: "He is clearly worried lest an agreement involving prices lower than he has been willing publicly to accept elsewhere, as well as payment of interest to US Governmental agency for loan although US has repeatedly been giving aid in form of ..." Still no sign the verb needed! Yes, it's severely truncated.

Comment: @LukeSawczak It is obvious from the extent of the OP's citation that the Google books result was the source. The complete second sentence from _Foreign Affairs, p 653,_ is _"He is clearly worried lest an agreement involving prices lower than he has been willing publicly to accept elsewhere, as well as payment of interest to US Governmental agency for loan although US has repeatedly been giving aid in form of large grants to neighboring cuntries, might give fresh ammunition to his political enemies."_ (The article addresses US involvement in the internal affairs of Iran. The "he" is Mossadegh.)

Answer (score 1):

The first part:

> During recent months he has been repeatedly accused of having "sold out" to US

means that he has repeatedly betrayed his own cause/convictions/people/etc to gain something from the US.

> He is clearly worried lest an agreement involving prices lower than he has been willing to accept elsewhere

The next part implies that he is involved in doing business with a lot of places and he is worried that an agreement will be made that will force him to accept prices that are lower than the prices that he usually accepts in the other places he does business. The *elsewhere* part means the other places he has been accepting higher prices from.

Now, I am probably wrong about the whole *business* thing but that's the best assumption I could make from the *price* context. It would help quite a bit if you included more context such as where this text is from or who 'he' is.